# Redirect http to https using Tomcat is not working

Tags: java, tomcat

### 1. What I want to do

I am currently creating a dynamic web application (JSP/Servlet), and try to setup SSL certificate in Tomcat (v8.5) to access from "https://[hostname]:8443/[AppName]".

### 2. Current Problem

I cannot reach the page "https://[hostname]:8443/[AppName]" and the following message is showing.

```
The connection timeout.
the response from the localhost server was not received at a certain time.
```

[Cannot connect to my app using https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dxea.jpg)

But somehow when I try to access the default Tomcat page, I can reach it successfully by "https://[hostname]:8443/"

[Can connect to Tomcat default using https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEU5h.jpg)

And of course I could connect to my app using "http", like "http://[hostname]:8080/TennisDatabase"
[Can connect using http](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8Wqp.jpg)

### 3. What I did

(1)Generated certificate.

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keypass [password] -keystore mycertificate.cer -storepass [password]
```

(2)Modify server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           scheme="https"
           secure="true"
           clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"
           keystoreFile="conf/mycertificate.cer" keystorePass="[password]" />
```

(3)Allow port 8443 from iptables.

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
```

(4)Modify server.xml
Also changed permission of file to 755.

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

(5)Restart Tomcat

### 4. Additional Info

When I try crul, I faced the following error.

```
$ curl -v --tlsv1.1 https://[hostname]:8443/[appname]
* About to connect() to [hostname] port 8443 (#0)
*   Trying [IP address]... connected
* Connected to [hostname] ([IP address]) port 8443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -5990
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

CentOS : 6.10
Tomcat : 8.5

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server.xml file has the right permission... and the main thing is you mention that you are using JSP/servlet so you have web.xml

**add these lines in web.xml**

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

Comment: Dear Azartheen, thank you very much for your suggestion. I updated web.xml but still haiving the same issue. I did some investigation using the curl command and some error message was shown (I wrote it on "4. Additional Info" section). I searched for this error, but still not getting the cause.